When declaring variables and objects inside class method, why does only the primitive type need to use 'let'?
For the following example
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  driveTypes: string[];
  vehicleTypes: string[];
  vehicle: Vehicle;
  test2:string;
  testObj2 :{key2:'value2'};

  method1(){
    let test1:string;
    let test2 = 'abc';
    test3:string; // 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
    test4 = 'def';  // Cannot find name 'test4'. Did you mean 'test1'?(2552)
    testObj : {key1:'value1'};
    let testObj2 : {key3:'value3'};
  }

Inside method1(), why test3, test4 has error and must use let keyword like
let test1:string;
let test2 = 'abc';

but
 testObj : {key1:'value1'};

has no any error?

To declare a variable within the context of a function, you need to use either let, const or var(wont recommend using var), testObj didn't return an error, because Typescript didnt recognize it as a variable declaration. Why is that? I am not sure. I have to dig into it

@T.Jami it'snot a declaration, it's a label. What does the JavaScript syntax foo: mean?

You are not really comparing the same things. You mixe declaration with assignation
test4 = 'def';  Error because it's not declared as a variable (let, const, var) before and you are trying to assign a value to something that doesn't exist.
testObj : {key1:'value1'}; Typescript doens't recognize it as a variable declaration but as a "type declaration". You defining the shape but without creating a value for it.
If you try to declare the variable like a = { key1: 'value1' }; you will have the same error.
However, this line (testObj : {key1:'value1'};) is also incomplete because you're not actually declaring the variable, you're just specifying its shape. If you try to use testObj later, TypeScript will throw an error because the variable itself doesn't exist in memory.

testObj : {key1:'value1'}; is a type declaration, not understand this, then if testObj is a type declaration, then how to use it?

@user1169587 "testObj : {key1:'value1'}; is a type declaration" it's not, it's a label.

@VLAZ if the testObj in testObj : {key1:'value1'}; is just a label, then the statement is just {key1:'value1'}, then what does it means? an object without name and not assign to any variable?

@VLAZ oh, if i move the mouse pointer to testObj, it will prompt "Unused label.(7028)", and if I move the mouse pointer to key1, it also show 'Unused label.(7028)', then really it is just a label, thanks, if you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as Answer, thanks.
